# Loop over 2 lists, repeating the shortest until end of longest

Tags: python, list, loops

I am sure there is an easy and obvious way to do this, but I have been googling and reading the docs and I just cannot find anything.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
la = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
lb = ['b1', 'b2']
result = ['a1_b1', 'a2_b2', 'a3_b1', 'a4_b2']
```

I have a list of dates and some of them have something marked on them. I then have a much larger list of dates and I want to put the smallest list inside the bigger list as many times as possible. It will probably require some sort of loop as I need access to the dates in the larger list for the end result.

For some reason, I just cannot see a good way to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to zip two differently sized lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686533/how-to-zip-two-differently-sized-lists)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try

```
result = ["_".join((i, j)) for i, j in itertools.izip(la, itertools.cycle(lb))]
```

Comment: [izip is replaced with built-in zip in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32659552/izip-not-working-in-python-3-x)

Comment: What to do if we don't know before which of `la` or `lb` will be exhausted first?

Answer (score 38):

Assuming `la` is longer than `lb`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [x+'_'+y for x,y in zip(la, itertools.cycle(lb))]
['a1_b1', 'a2_b2', 'a3_b1', 'a4_b2']
```

- `itertools.cycle(lb)` returns a cyclic iterator for the elements in `lb`.
- `zip(...)` returns a list of tuples in which each element corresponds to an element in `la` coupled with the matching element in the iterator.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools
la = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
lb = ['b1', 'b2']
for i, j in zip(la, itertools.cycle(lb)):
    print('_'.join((i,j)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using only zip, just repeat the shorter list.

```
[x+'_'+y for x,y in zip(la, lb*2)]
```