# Strange For Loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I am familiar with for loops on a basic level.  I use them quite often at school, but I just came across one online that I do not understand.  I was wondering if someone could possibly explain to me what kind of loop this is or if you could even tell me what type of loop it is.  I am willing to research it on my own, but am not finding anything.  The loop is below and can be found [here](http://code.jasonbhill.com/python/project-euler-problem-18/).

```
for i,j in [(i,j) for i in range(len(rows)-2,-1,-1) for j in range(i+1)]:
    rows[i][j] +=  max([rows[i+1][j],rows[i+1][j+1]])
```

Comment: It's a list comprehension.

Comment: poorly written mix a for loop and a list comprehension

Comment: It loops the rows bottom-up and add to each element the maximum between the two items below it, hence the final result will be in `rows[0][0]` (the first row which holds only a single item). This is not a poor implementation but rather a clever one, which belongs [*here*](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @alfasin I understood how the for loop worked from his explanation of it on the link provided.  I just did not understand the syntax of the for loop provided.  icktoofay's answer below helped me a lot though.  Thank you, all.

Comment: @alfasin (and others) Consider posting revised versions of your comments as answers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [python list comprehension explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/python-list-comprehension-explained)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a loop over a list comprehension. It could roughly be translated as:

```
temp = []
for i in range(len(rows) - 2, -1, -1):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        temp.append((i, j))
for (i, j) in temp:
    rows[i][j] += max([rows[i + 1][j], rows[i + 1][j + 1]])
```

Or, more directly:

```
for i in range(len(rows) - 2, -1, -1):
    for j in range(i + 1):
        rows[i][j] += max([rows[i + 1][j], rows[i + 1][j + 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The part in the `[ ... ]` is called a `List Comprehension` it produces a `List`.

Don't think this code is good code, it isn't a good example of maintainable code.