# How to convert a matrix of strings into a matrix of integers using comprehensions

Tags: python, list, matrix, list-comprehension

I have a matrix [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']] which I want to convert to a matrix of integers. Is there is a way to do it using comprehensions?

Comment: Try searching.  You'll find numerous such examples.

Comment: Have you tried anything?? Here is a link which might be helpful  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/python-list-comprehension-explained

Answer (score 2):

```
[ [int(a), int(b)] for a, b in matrix ]
```

Answer (score 2):

In the general case:

```
int_matrix = [[int(column) for column in row] for row in matrix]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like:

```
>>> test = [['1', '2'], ['3', '4']]
>>> [[int(itemInner) for itemInner in itemOuter] for itemOuter in test]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

As long as all the items are integer, the code could work.

Hope it be helpful!

Answer (score 0):

```
   [map(int, thing) for thing in matrix]
```