# Python append to an string element in a list

Tags: python

I'm fairly new to python. I want to know how can you append to a string element in a list cumulatively ?

```
list = ['1','2','3','4']
list2 = ['a','b','c','d']
```

I want a new list like this:

```
list3 = ['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d']
```

I've been running circles for possible answers. Help is much appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Sorry typo, yes there are strings.

Comment: do you want  `list3 = ['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d']` or `list3 = ['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']`?

Comment: Your result is bit misleading. DO you want to prefix `1` with all the elements of list2 or is it an adjacent concatenation?

Comment: Are you sure you want `['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d']` and not `['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) like so:

```
list = ['1','2','3','4']
list2 = ['a','b','c','d'] 

print map(lambda x: x[0] + x[1],zip(list,list2))
```

Output:

```
['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']
```

**Online Demo - https://repl.it/CaTY**

Answer (score 2):

Using [list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/python-list-comprehension-explained). Note that you need to turn the integer into a string via the `str()` function, then you can use string concatenation to combine list1[0] and every element in list2. Also note that `list` is a keyword in python, so it is not a good name for a variable.

```
>>> list1 = [1,2,3,4]
>>> list2 = ['a','b','c','d']
>>> list3 = [str(list1[0]) + char for char in list2]
>>> list3
['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d']
```

Comment: While code often speaks for itself, it's good to add some explanation to your code.

Answer (score 1):

In your question you want `list3 = ['1a', '1b', '1c', '1d']`.

If you really want this: list3 = `['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']` then:

```
>>> list = ['1','2','3','4']
>>> list2 = ['a','b','c','d'] 
>>> zip(list, list2)
[('1', 'a'), ('2', 'b'), ('3', 'c'), ('4', 'd')]
>>> l3 = zip(list, list2)
>>> l4 = [x[0]+x[1] for x in l3]
>>> l4
['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d']
>>>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'm assuming your goal is [ '1a', '2b', '3c', '4d' ] ?

```
list = [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]
list2 = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
list3 = []

for i in range (len(list)):
    elem = list[i] + list2[i]
    list3 += [ elem ]

print list3
```

In general though, I'd be careful about doing this. There's no check here that the lists are the same length, so if list is longer than list2, you'd get an error, and if list is shorter than list2, you'd miss information.

I would do this specific problem like this:

```
letters = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ]
numberedLetters = []

for i in range (len(letters)):
    numberedLetters += [ str(i+1) + letters[ i ] ]

print numberedLetters
```

And agree with the other posters, don't name your variable 'list' - not only because it's a keyword, but because variable names should be as informative as reasonably possible.