# How to create a list in Python with list comprehension (instead of for loop)

Tags: python, list

My apologies as I'm new to Python and struggling with list comprehensions.

I can make a simple list in the following way:

```
min = whatever arbitrary number (not integer)
step= whatever arbitrary number (not integer)
lower_bound[0] = min
for index = 1 to 9
    lower_bound[index] = lower_bound[index-1] + step
```

How do I be more Pythonic with list comprehension?  Also, what is a good resource on the basics of list comprehension?  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python list comprehension explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/python-list-comprehension-explained)

Comment: The code you've posted is not valid python.

Comment: list comprehension creates a new list, in your code you are modifying a list, which do you want?

Comment: Nor does it make sense. What is the point of `min = 0`? You never change its value, and `0 + step` is always equal to `step`.

Comment: You shouldn't use the names of built-in Python functions to name your variables (i.e. don't use `min` to denote your "minimum" variable, as `min` is a Python built-in).

Comment: List comprehensions are good for mapping a function across an iterable, filtering on some predicate, or a combination of both of those things. You can always achieve the same thing with a for-loop, and oftentimes it is more Python to use a loop. I would concentrate on mastering loops if I were you.

Comment: this sight may help you - http://www.python-course.eu/list_comprehension.php

Comment: My apology for a poorly framed question, and my appreciation for everyone's input.  This is what I wanted to accomplish (with list comprehension):    lb=[minimum + step*i for i in range(9)]

Answer (score 0):

```
minimum = 0

step = 2


lower_bound = [i for i in range(minimum, 9, step)]

print(lower_bound)
```

Is this what you were asking for?

Comment: What if minimum is not an integer?  minimum could be a negative real number such as -0.1259115.