# What is the fastest way to filter list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a list of string (~400K) where the longest string has ~220 chars.
the strings represented path to objects with "." as separator.

I am trying to build an auto-complete feature that allows the user to quickly pick objects from a list instead of typing their full path.

The auto-complete feature is based on filtering the database based on user input.

I tried the following approaches.

1. Using `filter` - benchmarked to ~0.8 seconds

   ```
   database = list()
   database.append("path.to.first.object")
   database.append("path.to.first.some.object.of.mine")
   ....
   database.append("path.to.last.object") # ~430K items 

   partial_name = "som"
   filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: partial_name in x, database))
   ```
2. `regex` approach - benchmark to ~0.15 seconds

   ```
   regex = re.compile(r"{0}".format(partial_name))
   filtered_list = list(filter(regex.search, database))
   ```

The above is expected to yield only `path.to.first.some.object.of.mine` object

I also considered `Trie` data structure but this one won't support the "regex" kind of filtering.

Is there a faster approach for filtering strings?

Comment: Related: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/118759/how-to-quickly-search-through-a-very-large-list-of-strings-records-on-a-databa

Comment: Your approach 1 is not a [list comprehension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/python-list-comprehension-explained).

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri: thanks for the feedback, you are absolutely correct, and edited in my question

Comment: Why is this tagged `tkinter`

Comment: @EL3PHANTEN: this is because the filtering is to display auto-complete reduced list for the user to select an object rather than typing its full path