# understanding the creation of the array of lists in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I was reading about how to declare a matrices in python and I find this question [How to define two-dimensional array in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6667201/how-to-define-two-dimensional-array-in-python)

It's work with me, but I understanding what was done here in part, what I don't understanding is the parameter before the "for" in both loops...So I going to my terminal and testing parts of this for one by one, so when I type:

```
0 for x in range(w):
```

I receive:

> File "< stdin >", line 1

So I try:

```
[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h):
```

receive:

> File "< stdin >", line 1
>       [0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h):

So I try:

```
[0 for x in range(w)]
```

and

```
[[0 for x in range(w)] for y in range(h)]
```

and it's work...

So why the loop works when I put the brackets and not work without the brackets?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: list comprehension is explained on several SO topics. here is one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/python-list-comprehension-explained

Comment: Thanks for the tip brother!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is list comprehension in python. And similar, there is also set comprehension, dict comprehension. It uses the elements in `for` loop to construct the list. Such as

```
>>> [2*i for i in range(10)]
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>> [i for i in range(10) if i % 2 == 1]
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> [0 for _ in range(10)]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> [[i for i in range(j)] for j in range(5)]
[[], [0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
>>> {i : chr(65+i) for i in range(5)}
{0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'C', 3: 'D', 4: 'E'}
```

---

1. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/
2. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Answer (score 1):

You need the brackets so that the python interpreter processes the operations within the brackets in the correct order. Otherwise, the statement is not being interpreted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)(please look over 5.1.4. Nested List Comprehensions of the link). The same task may be achieved [using generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060653/list-comprehension-without-in-python) which does not involve brackets, but a generator does not create a list.