# What does this code to flatten a list of lists mean?

Tags: python

I've come across this single line code, which is a function definition, that flattens a list of lists to produce a single list. Can someone explain to me, term by term, what does this mean? How does it work?

```
lambda l : [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

Comment: [List comprehension explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/python-list-comprehension-explained).

Comment: The syntax is wrong, it must have been `[item for sublist in l for item in sublist]`

Comment: Actually it's just a `SyntaxError`... but please explain what you don't understand. The `lambda`? The list-comprehension? Loops? Variables?

Comment: This seems to be a classical overuse of lambdas. It can just be a normal function.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly as far as I know there's no way to really blindly unpack an indefinitely nested list in python.

Op appears to have attempted to copy from

[Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

```
flatten = lambda l: [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

I tested the above on python 3.6, four-nested structure. Sadly it only unpacks the outer layer. I need to use it in a loop three times to fully unpack the structure.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(625).reshape(5,5,5,-1).tolist() #4-nested structure
flatten = lambda x: [item for sublist in x for item in sublist]
y = flatten(x) #results in 3-nested structure of length 25.
```

The same problem also exists for the more versatile below function (which requires an import):

```
from itertools import chain
y = list(chain.from_iterable(x)) #as per flatten() above, unpacks one level
```

For multiple layers and if you're not too concerned about overhead, you could just do the following:

```
import numpy as np
y = np.array(x).flatten().tolist() #where x is any list / tuple / numpy array / 
                          #iterable
```

Hope the above helps :)

p.s. Ahsanul Hafique's unpacking illustrates the logic of the lambda function as requested by op. I don't believe in lambda functions and you just have to look at Ahsanul's unpacking to see why. It would be trivial to factor out the unpacking , while in the main function check if the sublist is a list or list element, and unpack or append as appropriate and thus create a completely versatile list unpacker using two functions.

Answer (score 1):

It means converting a 2D list into a 1D list i.e a flat list.

For example if you have a list in the form:

```
lst = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

The output you wanted is:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]]
```

Let's see the function definition:

```
lambda l : [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```

Which equivalents:

```
def flatten(l):
    result = []
    for sublist in l:    # here shublist is one of the innerlists in each iteration 
        for item in sublist: # One item of a particular inner list 
            result.append(item) #Appending the item to a flat list.
    return result
```