# Understanding counter and dictionary comprehensions in python

Tags: python, dictionary, list-comprehension, counting, dictionary-comprehension

I have tried to find an explanation but couldn't, so my apologies if this is a silly question.

Having data x:

```
 x = [(1, {'gender': 'male'}),
      (2, {'gender': 'female'}),
      (3, {'gender': 'male'}),
      (4, {'gender': 'female'}),
      (5, {'gender': 'male'})]
      ...
```

A plausible solution for counting the occurrences of each gender would be:

```
from collections import Counter
Counter([d['gender'] for n, d in x)])
```

Returning:

```
Counter({'female':2, 'male':3})
```

Now I am trying to understand how "d['gender'] for n, d " works within "Counter([d['gender'] for n, d in x)]".
What exactly is "n" in this case?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: ... if you have a basic question, why do you choose to ask StackOverflow instead of read tutorials? Research please.

Comment: Not to mention that there are billions (not that much, but anyway) questions regarding list comprehension on SO. [For example this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-list-comprehension-works).

Comment: Thanks @user202729 I simply couldn't find a clear explanation for this dictionary setting, specifically what the n is in this case.

Comment: Short answer: `n` is an variable.

Comment: @liliscent Thanks, just a small tip: don't waste everyone's time commenting that someone doesn't understand something, without trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is a list, so `for <whatever> in x` iterates through `x` and assigns each element to `<whatever>`.

The elements of `x` are tuples, so you can use tuple assignment to assign each item in the tuple to a different variable. `for n, d in x` means that `n` is assigned the first item in the tuple, and `d` is assigned the second item.

So the first iteration does

```
n, d = (1, {'gender': 'male'})
```

This sets `n = 1` and `d = {'gender': 'male'}`.

the next iteration does

```
n, d = (2, {'gender': 'female'})
```

This sets `n = 2` and `d = {'gender': 'female'}`. And so on through the entire list.

Finally, the list comprehension returns a list of `d['gender']`, which is the `gender` element from the dictionaries.

`n` is not used, it was just needed as a placeholder so that `d` could be assigned to the second item in the tuples. It could also have been written as:

```
[el[1]['gender'] for el in x]
```

Comment: Thank you tremendously Barmar! This is so helpful!