# Selecting arrays in python under conditions

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, matrix

I have this array:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
 [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
 [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
 [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

I wish to create a new array, that will be only the rows that has 0 in column 1.

How can I build such array in python without writing up the function by myself. I have tried too complicated stuff and I just need simple selection method that gives me result.

@EDIT I forgot to mention that i am using numpy.array([])

Answer (score 3):

Since you are saying that you are using `numpy`, this is a good place for [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
a_new = a[np.where(a[:,1] == 0)]
print(a_new)
# array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
#        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
#        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. I tried select, search, find. It's "where" method. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

```
list = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
list = [item for item in list if item[1] == 0]
```

Output:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

If you're using `numpy` array, the first step is converting your numpy array to list using [tolist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method.

```
import numpy
array = numpy.array([[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])
list = [item for item in array.tolist() if item[1] == 0]
array = numpy.array(list)
```

Comment: Yeah i needed exactly that. But i actually forgot to mention that i am using numpy.array([]). So it's an object so i can't do this operation. Sorry for not being precise im noob in python.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the most efficient thing to do in OP's case (numpy). I suggest using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) instead

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way:

```
a = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

b = [l for l in a if len(l) > 1 and l[1] == 0]
print(b)
```

The output would be:

```
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: This answer checks the length of the array which is a good pratice.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [list comp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-list-comprehension-works)

```
l = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],[0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],[1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
l1 = [item for item in l if item[1] == 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
new_list = []
for i in list:
    has_zero = i[1]
    if has_zero==0:
        new_list.append(i)
print(new_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with list comprehensions as suggested in other answers as well as with `filter` that might be bit clearer semantically in your case:

```
>>> a = [[0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
...  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
...  [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
...  [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
...  [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
...  [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1],
...  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
...  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
...  [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
...  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
...  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
>>> filter(lambda row: row[1] == 0, a)
[[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: OP is using a numpy array