# Python access and sum dictionary values in list

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

I would like to know how can I access list values in a dictionary to sum them:

```
{'key1': [3, 1], 'key2': [0, 4], 'key3': [57492, 204652], 'key4': [1,3]}
```

I would like to sum the first element of each list sum(3,0,57492,1).

Is it possible to do so without any loop ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Have you looked at how to iterate over the values of a dictionary?

Comment: Yes, but every time I had to use a loop and I thought there was a way to access all the values in one go without iterating over all the dictionary.

Comment: One way or another, you *have* to iterate over the dictionary, whether that involves a list-comprehension, a for-loop, a while-loop, or some loop buried in the internals of `map`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to iterate over the entire dictionary which means you have to use loop.

It can simply be done with a list comprehension like:

```
sum([values[0] for key, values in dictionary.items()])
```

If the number of items in the dictionary are large in number then instead of `dictionary.items()` you can use a generator function

For Python 2.x:

```
for key, value in d.iteritems():
```

For Python 3.x:

```
for key, value in d.items():
```

You can read more on how to do list comprehension here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-list-comprehension-works)

Iterating over a dictionary: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3294889/iterating-over-dictionaries-using-for-loops)

Comment: First thank you very much, secondly would it be better if I use an iterator since I have a huge amount of values ? I read about it but I am fairly new in programming.

Comment: @Unic0 what is "huge"? If you want to use a memory-efficient verion, just use a generator-expression: `sum(v[0] for v in d.values())`. If you are on Python 2, use `d.itervalues()` instead.

Comment: Cool, yes you can use an iterator, but it will work the same way. List comprehension is also an iterator just written in one line in a simple way.

Comment: Also as @juanpa.arrivillaga pointed out you can use an iterator or a generator function if there are too many values in the list.

Comment: @VikashSingh a list-comprehension is not really an iterator.

Comment: Wow thank you ! Huge since I'll iterate over pixels values for images 640x640 and thousands of them !

Comment: @Unic0 True, List comprehension is not an iterator, it's an iterative way to build a list.

Comment: @VikashSingh Thank you very much for the advice, I tried many things but I thought I would be clearer to just put the question rather that all the tries. But noted ! Thank you again

Comment: No issues, I remember I used to get down-voted a lot in the early days. Just feels nice to be able to help someone. So thought I will give you a pointer. For a safer side you can always share what you have tried so far.

Comment: People want to see that you have put effort yourself before posting the question. Hope it makes sense. See you around :)