# variables in python comprehensions/ how do variables not given a value work

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
s = 'coffee coke tea lemonade milk sprite'

{ c:s.count(c) for c in ''.join([ w[1:] for w in s.split() 
  if 'e' not in w[-3:-1] and 'o' in w[:4] ]) }


# (’’.join([ w[1:] for w in s.split())
```

how does the `w` work is it run through the s.split() that has a total of 6 elements? or through each letter in the separated strings(e.g. 'coffee' etc. )? Why is the answer for this comprehension `{'o': 3, 'k': 2, 'e': 7, 'm': 2, 'n': 1, 'a': 2, 'd': 1}`.

I understand why it is a dictionary but the variable `c` and `w` are confusing to me, currently I think that the value for those variable are changing as the loop goes but I don't understand how the other code effects how they change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Explanation of how nested list comprehension works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-nested-list-comprehension-works)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to analyze how something works, take it apart:

```
s = 'coffee coke tea lemonade milk sprite'

d = { c:s.count(c) for c in ''.join([ w[1:] for w in s.split() 
  if 'e' not in w[-3:-1] and 'o' in w[:4] ]) }

print(d)
```

Output:

```
{'o': 3, 'k': 2, 'e': 7, 'm': 2, 'n': 1, 'a': 2, 'd': 1}
```

Lets take the parts as well:

```
print(list(w for w in s.split()))
print(list(w for w in s.split() if 'e' not in w[-3:-1] and 'o' in w[:4] ))
print(''.join([ w[1:] for w in s.split() if 'e' not in w[-3:-1] and 'o' in w[:4] ]))
```

Output:

```
['coffee', 'coke', 'tea', 'lemonade', 'milk', 'sprite']
['coke', 'lemonade']
okeemonade
```

So: `w` takes all values from s.split(),  which are `'coffee'`  `'coke'` `'tea'` `'lemonade'` `'milk'`  `'sprite'` but not all vaues are used, only those that pass `if 'e' not in w[-3:-1] and 'o' in w[:4]` with true AND then the part without the first character is fed to the next part of the comprehension.

The first part iterates over all characters in `'okeemonade'` and counts how often this letter occures inside  `s`.

Done.