# Structural breakdown of shorthand If Else statements

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I am trying to two shorthand If Else statements into a more conventional format, in order to understand it.

For example, from:

```
if-expression if (condition) else else-expression
```

to:

```
if condiction:
    if-expression
else:
    else-expression
```

Here are the actual statements I'm trying to breakdown:

Statement 1:

```
nc = [node_colors[node] if node in node_colors else 'none' for node in projected_routes.nodes()]
```

Statement 2:

```
ns = [20 if node in node_colors else 0 for node in projected_routes.nodes()]
```

Here are my attempts but they do not return the same results as above. I'm not sure what is the role of [] here.

Statement 1:

```
if node in node_colors:
    nc = node_colors[node]
else:
    for node in projected_routes.nodes():
        'none'
```

Statement 2:

```
if node in node_colors:
    ns = 20
else:
    for node in projected_routes.nodes():
        0
```

Where am I doing wrong? Please someone help me out with this.

Comment: You are overlooking the `for` part and how the precedence is handled by Python. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/20639180/5218354

Comment: @norok2 that is useful, cheers mate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this will work.

Statement 1:

```
nc=[]

for node in projected_routes.node():
    if node in node_colors:
        nc.append(node_colors[node])
    else:
        nc.append('none')
```

Statement 2:

```
ns=[]
for node in projected_routes.node():
    if node in node_colors:
        ns.append(20)
    else:
        ns.append(0)
```

On your tries, you have some mistakes:

- order/logic mistakes (where/which loop/conditional to use)
- assignment instead of append

  ```
  if node in node_colors:
              nc = node_colors[node]
  ```

Above, the 'value' of nc will be replaced for each iteration.

```
for node in projected_routes.nodes():
        0
```

Above sample, 0 is 'left in the air'; not appended, not assigned.

About the logic (learning):

```
[ expression if conditional else other thing for this many times ]
```

Translates to:

```
for this many times:
    if conditional: 
        do this thing
    else:
        do something else
```

Comment: You made it very clear and the statements you have provided works perfectly too, thank you @andreis11! Cheers

Comment: Glad it help @LiveRed1994! Cheers