# What does `var = [ ... ]` do in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In my Python program, I was told that this code snippet:

```py
listOfNumbers = input() # (This inputs a space separated list of integers)
listOfNumbers = listOfNumbers.split()

for x in range(0, len(listOfNumbers)):
    listOfNumbers[x] = int(x)
```

Can be replaced by this one-liner:

```py
listOfValues = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

I am new to Python so I don't know many code-shortening techniques or methods, so I started to analyse the snippet given.

I am confused about why part of the line is wrapped in square brackets: `[int(x) for x in input().split()]`

What do the `[` and `]` at the start and end of that section of code do?

Comment: The term to google is "list comprehension".

Comment: It indicates to python we are iterating and appending values to a list.

Comment: It's a list comprehension. It creates a list using the inner for loop.

Comment: Read [explanation-of-how-nested-list-comprehension-works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-nested-list-comprehension-works) for some more complex list comprehensions. Also read the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: This is not True. Your first code does not change the content of the list at all - the `x=int(x)` only works for that specific `x` inside the loop when you are there. NOT modifying the original list.

Comment: Another way to tackle what the list comp does, would be `listOfValues = list(map(int, input.split()))`

Comment: @Ary you made it worse. x is a string, you cannot index a list by a string.

Comment: @PatrickArtner `listOfValues = list(map(int, input.split()))` doesn't work: `AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: `listOfValues = list(map(int, input().split()))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's what is known as a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python).

Consider you want to make the first 5 numbers of the number line into a list.

The complete block of code would be written as:

```
myList = []
for i in range(1, 6):
    myList.append(i)
```

This can be shortened in a comprehension into:

```
myList = [i for i in range(1, 6)]
myList
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

It has other applications but it can be used to make a list in a fewer set of lines as above.

The square brackets, as you can see also exist in the main list, so it highlights the fact that a list is being made.

This can be seen more clearly if you wish to make a dictionary.

```
myDict = {key: 0 for key in range(1, 6)}
myDict
>>> {1: 0, 2: 0, 3: 0, 4: 0, 5: 0}
```

Comment: Wow, you got there 6 sec before me! :-)

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension is a syntactic sugar in python (that is faster). The `[` and `]` are list creators:

```py
x = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

List comprehension simplifies that to this:

```py
x = [x for x in range(0, 10 + 1)]
```