# Delete "nan" in python list

Tags: python, list

I'm new in python and I have a simple question
how could I delete the first "nan" of this list but maintain the second in case the value is duplicated.

for example:

```
my_list = ['experiencia: 4',
           'nan',
          'experiencia: 2',
           'nan',
           'nan',
          'experiencia: 10',
           'nan',
          'experiencia: 2',
           'nan',
          'experiencia: 3',
           'nan',
           'nan',
           'nan',
           'experiencia: 9',
           'nan',
           'experiencia: 10']
```

and the output I want to obtain is the following:

```
 my_list = ['experiencia: 4',
          'experiencia: 2',
           'nan',
          'experiencia: 10',
          'experiencia: 2',
          'experiencia: 3',
           'nan',
           'nan',
           'experiencia: 9',
           'experiencia: 10']
```

Comment: Have you tried coding it up yet? sometimes when it's tricky to figure out how to go about implementing something, it helps to break it up into a flow chart of individual steps.

Comment: I also would point out, it is often easier to build a new list rather than trying to modify an existing one in-place.

Answer (score 2):

You can ... get creative:

Group the whole list by its contents and disassemle the grouping again. If the key is a `"nan"` you need to use one less then the groupings value has elements - for non-`"nan"` use the grouping value as is. Lastly, remove empty `"nan"` - groupings (key = `"nan"`, value = `["nan"]` gets reduced to [] due to subtracting one):

```
my_list = ['experiencia: 4',
           'nan',
          'experiencia: 2',
           'nan',
           'nan',
          'experiencia: 10',
           'nan',
          'experiencia: 2',
           'nan',
          'experiencia: 3',
           'nan',
           'nan',
           'nan',
           'experiencia: 9',
           'nan',
           'experiencia: 10']

from itertools import groupby


result = [x for y in (list(amount) if value != "nan" else ["nan"] * (len(list(amount))-1)
                  for value, amount in groupby(my_list)) for x in y if x]
print(result)
```

Output (reformatted):

```
['experiencia: 4', 
 'experiencia: 2', 
 'nan', 
 'experiencia: 10', 
 'experiencia: 2',
 'experiencia: 3', 
 'nan', 
 'nan', 
 'experiencia: 9', 
 'experiencia: 10']
```

---

Readup:

- [Explanation of how nested list comprehension works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-nested-list-comprehension-works) (as to how the get rid of `[]` and unstacking of inner lists works)

Comment: thanks a lot! i was using the Pandas Series and dropping the index using a similar criteria, but your way to do it is better than mine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create a list for the indices you wish to do delete and delete them using the pop method

```
delete_list = [1,2,4,5,6,9]
newlist = ''
for i in delete_list:
   my_list.pop(i)
print (my_list)
```

> Result

```
['experiencia: 4', 'experiencia: 2', 'nan', 'experiencia: 10', 'experiencia: 2', 'experiencia: 3', 'nan', 'nan', 'experiencia: 9', 'experiencia: 10']
```

Note also, that i have shifted my deletion pattern to suit the index adjustment after every deletion

Answer (score -1):

```
my_list.remove('nan')
```

will delete only the first 'nan'

Comment: but not the first nan of every nan occurences

Answer (score -1):

This will also give you the desired output:

```
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import chain
my_list = [*chain.from_iterable([[k] * (len([*v]) - 1) if k == "nan" else [k] for k, v in groupby(my_list)])]
```