# How to swap even lesser elements with odd greater elements in a python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a list of elements from 1 to n, (`range(1, n + 1)`)

How should I swap odd greater elements with the even elements?

for example, if I have a list with elements `[1,2,3]` the desired output will be `[1,3,2]` because odd 3 is greater than even 2 .

example 2:

```
if list = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

the desired output will be

```
[1,3,2,5,4]
```

Here 2 will be swapped with 3 and 4 will be swapped with 5 but not with 3 because 3 is smaller than 4.

Comment: what is the desired in case that the closest greater odd element is ident for two elements like this case? `[2,4,5]` ?

Comment: This case is not possible because we will have a array always in a sequence of 1....n

Comment: So are you actually asking how to create such array for a given `n`?

Comment: Also please decide whether you're using Python 2 or 3. If your question is not version specific, remove both

Answer (score 4):

A simple for loop, to modify the list in place:

```
l = list(range(1,10))

for i, n in enumerate(l):
    if i % 2 != 0 and i < len(l) - 1:
        l[i] = l[i+1]
        l[i+1] = n
```

At every odd index, the element swaps places with its successor.

Comment: You can convert the `i < len(l) - 1` condition to be inside `enumerate(l[:-1])`

Answer (score 3):

You can use list slicing of even/odd numnbers, [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) them and create a solution list from that:

```
def interleave(n):
    k = list(range(1, n))

    k[:] = k[:1]+[y for x in zip(k[2::2], k[1::2]) 
            for y in x] + (k[-1:] if len(k)%2 == 0 else [])

    return k

print(interleave(20))
print(interleave(21))
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11, 10, 13, 12, 15, 14, 17, 16, 19, 18]
[1, 3, 2, 5, 4, 7, 6, 9, 8, 11, 10, 13, 12, 15, 14, 17, 16, 19, 18, 20]
```

Explanation:

- you keep the 1
- you get all odd ones from position 2 to end, stepsize 2
- you get all even ones from position 1 to end, stepsize 2
- you interleave them using zip
- you recombine them using a nested list comprehension of `[x for y in sequence for y in x]` where `y` are the tuples resulting by zipping two slices
- you compensate for even/odd sized input lists

Further reading:

- [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)
- [Explanation of how nested list comprehension works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-nested-list-comprehension-works)

Comment: To be consistent with OP you want `k = list(range(1, n+1))` to get list to be 1..n inclusive.

Comment: @DarrylG the OP never showed how he creates his list - but if wanted your suggestion would fix my method to do `n` inclusively - I chose exclusively.

Comment: @PatrickArtner--True, that's why I upvoted your answer with my suggestion.