# how does this line 2d array to 1d array conversion work?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I am able to get it to work but I don't understand how it works

```
li=[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
li2 = [ y for x in li for y in x]
```

output:
li2: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Explanation of how nested list comprehension works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-nested-list-comprehension-works)

Comment: `[elem for sublist in li for elem in sublist ]`

Answer (score 0):

Second line can be written as:

```
li2 = []
for x in li:
    for y in x:
        li2.append(y)
```