# How can i assign multiple keys the same value | python

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python, how can we assign multiple dictionary keys the same value.
I tried something below but it's not working.

```
server = {'server1','server2': 'abc@xyz.com', 'server3','server4':'pqr@xyz.com'}
```

Comment: You must list them separately.

Comment: `server = {'server1': 'abc@xyz.com', 'server2': 'abc@xyz.com', 'server3': 'pqr@xyz.com', 'server4': 'pqr@xyz.com'}`

Comment: By listing them separately it's working fine but how can we have multiple keys with the same value.

Comment: `server = {('server1','server2'): 'abc@xyz.com', ('server3','server4'):'pqr@xyz.com'}`

Comment: When I am doing server.keys() and search server1 or server2 it's not working

Comment: could you please improve the question? the English is not making proper sense of what you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you order your inputs as list of tuples, where each tuple is the value and a list of servers, you can use a nested list comprehension to create your dictionary:

```
from pprint import pprint

# arange your inputdata as tuples of ("value" to be set, list of servers)
# data = [ (f"login_{v}",[f"server_{v}{10+w}" for w in range(3)]) for v in range(5)]

data =  [ ('login_0', ['server_010', 'server_011', 'server_012']),
          ('login_1', ['server_110', 'server_111', 'server_112']),
          ('login_2', ['server_210', 'server_211', 'server_212']),
          ('login_3', ['server_310', 'server_311', 'server_312']),
          ('login_4', ['server_410', 'server_411', 'server_412']) ]

# create the dict using a nested list comprehension
d = {k:v for v,keys in data for k in keys}
pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
# of the created dict using a nested list comprehension
{'server_010': 'login_0',
 'server_011': 'login_0',
 'server_012': 'login_0',
 'server_110': 'login_1',
 'server_111': 'login_1',
 'server_112': 'login_1',
 'server_210': 'login_2',
 'server_211': 'login_2',
 'server_212': 'login_2',
 'server_310': 'login_3',
 'server_311': 'login_3',
 'server_312': 'login_3',
 'server_410': 'login_4',
 'server_411': 'login_4',
 'server_412': 'login_4'}
```

See [Explanation of how nested list comprehension works?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-nested-list-comprehension-works) if you do not know about those.

Answer (score 2):

For example:

```
s = "the_value" # the value you want for the keys below
l = ["name", "age", "address"] # keys
d = {} # initiating an empty dictionary
for item in l:
    d[item] = s
```

This should print

```
{'name': 'the_value', 'age': 'the_value', 'address': 'the_value'}
```

Comment: In this case I have multiple sets of keys and value ans storing each of them in variable would complicate the things.

Comment: @TrueEntertainer you either work with what the language got, or your code is faulty - pick one.

Comment: Probably you can also look into zip function then.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *tuples* as keys but then it is difficult to find the dictionary entry corresponding to a single value

```
server = {('server1','server2','serverX'): 'abc@xyz.com', \
          ('server3','server4'):'pqr@xyz.com'}
```

Note: you can do that because tuples are *hashable*.

This makes only sense if you want to query the dictionary by exactly such tuples, for instance:

```
server[('server3', 'server4')]                                                                                                                                                
# Out: 'pqr@xyz.com'
```

Comment: when i am doing userInput in server.keys() and searching for server3 it's not showing the output