# Python Advanced Nested Loop: [ (a, b) for a in range(3) for b in range(a) ]

Tags: python, nested-loops

Can someone explain to me step by step to understand how to arrive at the result of this loop?

```
>>> [ (a, b) for a in range(3) for b in range(a) ]
[(1, 0), (2, 0), (2, 1)]
```

Comment: Sorry for misreading my question being new to StackOverFlow. Thanks to @jonrsharpe for editing this. However, making me diminish my reputation is not cool. Explaining myself would have been more profitable.

Comment: Please stop unformatting the code. If you don't want to get downvotes, there's lots of guidance at e.g. [ask].

Comment: Ok. I had a display error and barely discovering StackOverFlow. Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 3):

It's equivalent to this:

```py
rtrn = []
for a in range(3):
    for b in range(a):
        rtrn.append((a, b))
```

Note how the first iteration of the outer loop does not produce any output because the inner loop is then `range(0)` which does zero iterations.

Comment: Thank you for your response and your responsiveness, I will try to think about it but I admit that I have not yet fully understood.

Comment: @Xcoder It often helps to put print statements in various places to see the order of operations. Also don't feel too bad about it. Even as a seasoned Python programmer I find the double loop in list comprehensions confusing and I try to avoid it. Oh, and if you are satisfied with my answer, please mark it as correct.

Comment: I marked your answer as correct it was obligatory for me. Yes it is true that print() in these cases is useful I had completely forgotten. I was taken down my reputation because I misspoke my question. The old ones are hard on the new ones ... Thank you again very much for your answer.

Comment: You don't see my extra point because I don't have enough reputation right now, sorry for that. The elders should have more understandings ... It's a shame.

Comment: @Xcoder - you can also try out in this great platform for small program execution's to see each steps `changes` in variables - https://pythontutor.com/

Comment: Another good S/O explained this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/