# Python simple 2d array while loop problem

Tags: python, list

I have spent numerous hours on this and still can't see what is wrong with my while loop.

```
i  = 0
while(i < points):
    trainingset[i][0] = firstx[i]
    trainingset[i][1] = firsty[i]
    trainingset[i][2] = 1
    
    i+= 1

print(trainingset)
```

I want the while loop to loop over every array inside `trainingset`such that `trainingset[0] = [firstx[0], firsty[0], 1]` and `trainingset[points-1] = [firstx[points-1], firsty[points-1], 1]`.

However, the code seems to loop over ever subarray of `trainingset` for each iteration of `i`, such that at the end `trainingset[0] = [firstx[points-1], firsty[points-1], 1]`and so does every single subarray of `trainingset`.

What is wrong with this while loop?

P.S `firstx` and `firsty` are 1d arrrays like `[1,2,3]` and `points` is a number.

Comment: Did you initialize `trainingset` with something like `trainingset = [[0,0,0] * points]`? It seems that you initialized `trainingset` to hold many references to the exact same list. See [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/240178/11082165)

Comment: As a side note, a `while` loop is generally a poor choice for any sort of index-based or sequential iteration. At very least `for i in range(points)` or `for example_list in trainingset` would be more conventional. But in this case your best choice would probably be a simple list compression: `trainingset = [[x,y,1] for x, y in zip(firstx, firsty)]`

Comment: Thank you for that Brian! I did initialize the training set like that. For next time how should I initialize it?

Comment: But Brian, how would I do such a list compression if I want the first `point` subarrays to be `[[x,y,1] for x, y in zip(firstx, firsty)]` and the next `point` subarrays to be `[[x,y,1] for x, y in zip(secondx, secondy)]`

Comment: It's very rare that you ever need to initialize a collection in python. Usually it's simpler (and safer) to just append entries as needed. Either using a list compression as in my comment above or initializing trainingset as a empty list and using `trainingset.append([..., ..., ...])` as required would likely be your best options.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for something like `[[x,y,1] for xs, ys in [(firstx, firsty), (secondx, secondy), ...] for x,y in zip(xs, ys)]`, or something altogether simpler depending on how `firstx`, `secondx`, etc were obtained in the first place. If you only need to iterate `trainingset` once, you might also just use `itertools.chain` to consecutively iterate over each of `firstx`, `secondx`, etc in one go.

Comment: So in that case what would xs and ys be?

Comment: See [Explanation of how nested list comprehension works?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20639180/11082165). `(xs, ys)` takes on `(firstx, firsty)` in the first iteration, `(secondx, secondy)` in the second, and so on.