# How to convert to size 0 array

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[2], [1], [3]])

A.shape  # (3, 1)

A.reshape(3,0)
```

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-771b3dbc4936> in <module>
----> 1 A.reshape(3,0)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 3 into shape (3,0)
```

Comment: What is your desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[2], [1], [3]])
A = [a for b in A for a in b]
print(A)
```

Results in: [2, 1, 3]

if this is what you were looking for

Comment: can you please explain how this loop [a for b in A for a in b] works?

Comment: @DebluSahu Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20639180/explanation-of-how-nested-list-comprehension-works) to see how nestled list comprehension works :)

Answer (score 0):

Please tell us about what exactly you want to achive?

A shape of (3, 1) means you have an array with two axis; one with the length of 3, and the second with one element each. Reshaping it to shape (3, 0) would give something like [[], [], []] (3 elements in the first axis and zero in the second), which doesnt really make any sense

Comment: I am working on matrices so to make shape of each matrices it needed