# Write lists of different size to csv in columns in Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I need to write lists that all differ in length to a CSV file in columns.

I currently have:

```
d=lists
writer = csv.writer(fl)
for values in zip(*d):
    writer.writerow(values)
```

which works only partially. What I suspect is happening is that it stops zipping up until the lists with the list of the shortest length.

Comment: What programming language do you use and what csv lib?

Comment: Your issue is with how you are using zip. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686533/how-to-zip-two-different-size-list-in-python

Comment: @Krets I'm not sure that's the same question, though; the solutions there repeat the lists (like in `R`).

Comment: Also, `d` is just a list of lists, right?

Comment: yes, d is a list of lists

Comment: @Al.Sal You are correct. The answer I linked to relates to only two lists whereas this is for a list of lists. Regardless, the issue remains zip() will return a list that matches the length of the shortest input list. Sameer must manipulate all the lists to be the same length before using zip. The first answer seems like it would get it done.

Comment: Hm. Then why not transpose the lists first? That would clean up code readibility-wise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Code below is for Python 3. If you use Python 2, import izip_longest instead of zip_longest.

```
import csv
from itertools import zip_longest

d = [[2,3,4,8],[5,6]]

with open("file.csv","w+") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for values in zip_longest(*d):
        writer.writerow(values)
```

Result:

```
2,5
3,6
4,
8,
```

Comment: This created an empty row between every row

Answer (score 2):

There's no 'neat' way to write it since, as you said, zip truncates to the length of the shortest iterable.

Probably the simplest way would be to just pad with None or empty strings (Not sure offhand what the behavior of writerow is with None values):

```
maxlen = max([len(member) for member in d])
[member.extend([""] * (maxlen - len(member))) for member in d]
for values in zip(*d):
    ...
```

Alternatively, you could just construct each row inside the for loop instead of using `zip`, which would be more efficient but a lot wordier.

EDIT: corrected example