# Generate a sequence of number and alternating string in python

Tags: python, list

**Aim**

I would like to generate a sequence as `list` in `python`, such as:

```
['s1a', 's1b', 's2a', 's2b', ..., 's10a', 's10b']
```

Properties:

- items contain a single *prefix*
- *numbers* are sorted numerical
- *suffix* is alternating per number

**Approach**

To get this, I applied the following code, using an `xrange` and comprehensive list approach:

```
# prefix
p = 's'
# suffix
s = ['a', 'b']
# numbers
n = [ i + 1 for i in list(xrange(10))]
# result
[ p + str(i) + j for i, j in zip(sorted(n * len(s)), s * len(n)) ]
```

**Question**

Is there a more simple syntax to obtain the results, e.g. using `itertools`?
Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686533/how-to-zip-two-different-size-list-in-python#19686624) question?

Comment: FWIW, `sorted(n * len(s))` is an inefficient way to create that list, it would be better to do the replication inside the list comprehension that creates `n`. Also, `list(xrange(...))` is an anti-pattern: if you want an actual list, just use `range`. (Of course, in Python 3, `range` returns a range object, not a list, so you _do_ have to wrap it in a `list` call when you want an actual list).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A doubled-for list comprehension can accomplish this:

```
['s'+str(x)+y for x in range(1,11) for y in 'ab']
```

Comment: I count the usage of *doubled* list comprehension, as well as `range` instead `xrange` as improvement. Will accept answer in case no better solutions are found. Thanks.

Comment: @setempler: using `range` also makes it compatible with Python 3.  :)

Answer (score 3):

`itertools.product` might be your friend:

```
all_combos = ["".join(map(str, x)) for x in itertools.product(p, n, s)]
```

returns:

```
['s1a', 's1b', 's2a', 's2b', 's3a', 's3b', 's4a', 's4b', 's5a', 's5b', 's6a', 's6b', 's7a', 's7b', 's8a', 's8b', 's9a', 's9b', 's10a', 's10b']
```

EDIT: as a one-liner:

```
all_combos = ["".join(map(str,x)) for x in itertools.product(['s'], range(1, 11), ['a', 'b'])]
```

EDIT 2: as pointed out in James' answer, we can change our listed string element in the `product` call to just strings, and `itertools` will still be able to iterate over them, selecting characters from each:

```
all_combos = ["".join(map(str,x)) for x in itertools.product('s', range(1, 11), 'ab')]
```

Comment: Great! `itertools.product` is a nice example!

Comment: Is it possible to simplify `['a', 'b']` to `'ab'`, as in the answer of James?

Comment: @setempler Why don't you try it?

Comment: @setempler @StefanPochmann I've updated it to include this - ditto the `'s'`, which doesn't really need to be a list here.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
def func(prefix,suffixes,size):
    k = len(suffixes)
    return [prefix+str(n/k+1)+suffixes[n%k] for n in range(size*k)]

# usage example:
print func('s',['a','b'],10)
```

This way you can alternate as many suffixes as you want.

And of course, each one of the suffixes can be as long as you want.

Comment: A function was not my intention to use, but the `return` statement clearly yields an interesting approach to generalise the method.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a double-list comprehension, where you iterate on number and suffix. You don't need to load any

Below is a lambda function that takes 3 parameters, a prefix, a number of iterations, and a list of suffixes

```
foo = lambda prefix,n,suffix: list(prefix+str(i)+s for s in suffix for i in range(n))
```

You can use it like this

```
foo('p',10,'abc')
```

Or like that, if your suffixes have more than one letter

```
foo('p',10,('a','bc','de'))
```

Comment: `lambda` is for creating anonymous functions, so it's generally considered bad style to bind a `lambda` to a name. If you want to write a named function you should use the proper `def` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

For maximum versatility I would do this as a generator. That way you can either create a list, or just produce the sequence items as they are needed.

Here's code that runs on Python 2 or Python 3.

```
def psrange(prefix, suffix, high):
    return ('%s%d%s' % (prefix, i, s) for i in range(1, 1 + high) for s in suffix)

res = list(psrange('s', ('a', 'b'), 10))
print(res)

for s in psrange('x', 'abc', 3):
    print(s)
```

**output**

```
['s1a', 's1b', 's2a', 's2b', 's3a', 's3b', 's4a', 's4b', 's5a', 's5b', 's6a', 's6b', 's7a', 's7b', 's8a', 's8b', 's9a', 's9b', 's10a', 's10b']
x1a
x1b
x1c
x2a
x2b
x2c
x3a
x3b
x3c
```