# How can I run through 2 lists at the same time in python?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to print things from 2 lists one after another.

```
ls1 = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Morty']
ls2 = ['Pineapple', 'Carrot', 'Rick', 'Tangelo']
```

I would usually do:

```
for fruit in ls1:
    print(fruit)
for fruit in ls2
    print(fruit)
```

but that will cycle though one list then the other. I want the output to alternate between the lists in order:

```
Apple
Pineapple
Orange
...etc...
```

or

```
ls1[0]
ls2[0]
ls1[1]
ls2[1]
...etc...
```

Comment: If list are of different size take a look into: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19686624/5916727

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(len(ls1)):
    print(ls1[i])
    print(ls2[i])
```

given if length of ls1 is equal to length of ls2

Comment: zip would be preferred, I think

Comment: Agree with @cricket_007 you got lucky that OP's real life scenario is such that both lists are of equal length. Not only does your answer lack robustness its also non-pythoninc

Comment: I know that but I just tried to be simple for the beginner.Thats it

Answer (score 5):

IMHO a more pythonic way would be:

```
ls_1 = ["Apple", "Orange", "Banana", "Morty"]
ls_2 = ["Pineapple", "Carrot", "Rick", "Tangelo"]

for i, j in zip(ls_1, ls_2):
    print(i, j)
```

Answer (score 3):

Zip is more reliable here

```
for i, j in zip(ls1, ls2):
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

zip takes care if your list are not of same length.

it stops at the length of a shorter list.

Answer (score 2):

I would take care of different sizes of both the list scenario too.

```
ls1 = ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana', 'Morty', 'Cherries', 'Avacado']
ls2 = ['Pineapple', 'Carrot', 'Rick', 'Tangelo']

for i in range(max(len(ls1), len(ls2))):
    if (i < len(ls1)):
        print(ls1[i])
    if (i < len(ls2)):
        print(ls2[i])
```

Comment: Nice but not pythonic, see answer of @itghisi