# Cleanest way to iterate over pair of iterables of different lengths, wrapping the shorter iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterable

If I have two iterables of different lengths, how can I most cleanly pair them, re-using values from the shorter one until all values from the longer are consumed?

For example, given two lists

```
l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
l2 = ['x', 'y']
```

It would be desirable to have a function `fn()` resulting in pairs:

```
>>> fn(l1, l2)
[('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'x')]
```

I found I could write a function to perform this as such

```
def fn(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) > len(l2):
        return [(v, l2[i % len(l2)]) for i, v in enumerate(l1)]
    return [(l1[i % len(l1)], v) for i, v in enumerate(l2)]

>>> fn(l1, l2)
[('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'x')]
>>> l2 = ['x', 'y', 'z', 'w']
>>> fn(l1,l2)
[('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'z'), ('a', 'w')]
```

However, I'm greedy and was curious **what other methods exist?** so that I may select the most obvious and elegant and be wary of others.

[`itertools.zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) as suggested in many similar questions is very close to my desired use case as it has a `fillvalue` argument which will pad the longer pairs. However, this only takes a single value, instead of wrapping back to the first value in the shorter list.

As a note: in my use case one list will always be much shorter than the other and this may allow a short-cut, but a generic solution would be exciting too!

Comment: just added `[*zip(A*(len(B)//len(A) + 1), B*(len(A)//len(B) + 1))]` to [how-to-zip-two-differently-sized-lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686533/how-to-zip-two-differently-sized-lists)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [`itertools.cycle()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) with [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) to get the desired behavior.

As the [**`itertools.cycle()`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) document says, it:

> Make an iterator returning elements from the iterable and saving a copy of each. When the iterable is exhausted, return elements from the saved copy.

For example:

```
>>> l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l2 = ['x', 'y']

>>> from itertools import cycle
>>> zip(l1, cycle(l2))
[('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'x')]
```

Since in your case, length of `l1` and `l2` could vary, your generic `fn()` should be like:

```
from itertools import cycle

def fn(l1, l2):
    return zip(l1, cycle(l2)) if len(l1) > len(l2) else zip(cycle(l1), l2)
```

Sample Run:

```
>>> l1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> l2 = ['x', 'y']

# when second parameter is shorter 
>>> fn(l1, l2)
[('a', 'x'), ('b', 'y'), ('c', 'x')]

# when first parameter is shorter
>>> fn(l2, l1)
[('x', 'a'), ('y', 'b'), ('x', 'c')]
```

Comment: @rassar I was on my way to write that :)

Answer (score -1):

If you're not sure which one is the shortest, `next` `it.cycle` the longest `len` of the two lists:

```
def fn(l1, l2):
    return (next(zip(itertools.cycle(l1), itertoools.cycle(l2))) for _ in range(max((len(l1), len(l2)))))

>>> list(fn(l1, l2))

[('a', 'x'), ('a', 'x'), ('a', 'x')]
```

`itertools.cycle` will repeat the list infinitely. Then, `zip` the two infinite lists together to get the cycle that you want, but repeated infinitely. So now, we need to trim it to the right size. `max((len(l1), len(l2)))` will find the longest length of the two lists, then `next` the infinite iterable until you get to the right length. Note that this returns a generator, so to get the output you want use `list` to eat the function.