# how to iterate through two lists?

Tags: python, loops

In my python code, I have two iterable list.

```
num = [1, 2, 3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,]

alpa = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

for (a, b) in itertools.izip_longest(num, alpa):

   print a, b
```

the output:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 None
6 None
```

my expected output:

```
1 a
2 b
3 c
4 d
5 a
6 b
```

How do I make it happen?

Comment: Dulicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686533/how-to-zip-two-differently-sized-lists

Comment: The answer there: use `itertools.cycle`

Comment: @Barmar: you have a python gold badge. Why can't your vote close this as a duplicate?

Comment: @Bazingaa Been busy last night, hit the limit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools.cycle`. Here is some Python 3 code. Note that `zip` is used rather than `izip_longest` since `cycle` creates an infinite iterator and you want to stop when the one list is finished.

```
import itertools

num = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] 

alpa = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'] 

for (a, b) in zip(num, itertools.cycle(alpa)):

   print(a, b)
```

Comment: nice, thank you :)