# How can I multiply two lists of different lengths in such a way that the shorter list repeats?

Tags: python, list

I need to multiply these two lists together but one is very long and the other is very short, the long list's length is a multiple of the short one's length.  How can I multiply them in a way that the short one is repeated until all of the elements in the long list have been multiplied by it.

For example:

```py
longList = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10] 
shortList = [1, 2, 3]
```

#### What I am trying to do:

```py
longList * shortList # Something like this
```

#### Desired output

```
[10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]
```

*This is not a duplicate of [How to zip two differently sized lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686533/how-to-zip-two-differently-sized-lists) because I am not looking to zip them, but rather to multiply them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to zip two differently sized lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686533/how-to-zip-two-differently-sized-lists)

Comment: I probably should have used integers in `longList`, I do in fact want to multiply the two lists instead of zipping them.  @uneven_mark

Comment: Zipping is only the preparation. You must then use it in a list comprehension: `[a*b for a,b in zip_list]`. I assumed that this was not what you are asking about.

Comment: Is your question about zipping two lists of different lengths?

Comment: @DanielMesejo I didn't think that it was but uneven_mark 's comment above answered my question

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve this with a simple loop and itertools

```
import itertools

longList = [1, 0, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1]
shortList = [1, 2, 3]

output_list = []

for long, short in zip(longList, itertools.cycle(shortList)):
    output_list.append(long * short)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

The following code will work even if the number of elements in `longList` is not an exact multiple of `shortList`. And it does not require any `import` statements either.

```py
longList = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,] 
shortList = [1, 2, 3]

container = list()
n = len(longList)%len(shortList)
m = int(len(longList)/len(shortList))
for _ in range(m):
    container += shortList.copy()     
if n>0:
    container += shortList[:n]
[e*f for e,f in zip(container, longList)]
```

**Output**:

```
[10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

The following pythonic function (using a [list comprehension](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)) should work:

```
def loop_multiply(ll,sl) : 
    return [ x*sl[i%len(sl)] for i,x in enumerate(ll) ] 


print(loop_multiply([10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10],[1,2,3])) 
# prints - [10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30, 10, 20, 30]
```

Hope that helps :)