# adding list of different lengths together

Tags: list, sorting, arraylist, zip

Say I have two list

```
firstlist = ['A','B','C','D','E']

secondlist = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']
```

I want to combine one item in `firstlist` with another item in `secondlist`

So I can I have:

```
[('A', '1'), ('B', '2'), ('C', '3'), ('D', '4'), ('E', '5'), ('A', '6'), ('B', '7'), ('C', '8'), ('D', '9'), ('E', '10')]
```

I know I could use the `zip` function but since one list is longer, it would stop at the shorter list

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a zip-like function that pads to longest length in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277278/is-there-a-zip-like-function-that-pads-to-longest-length-in-python)

Comment: Wait, no, it doesn't. What you want is to combine `zip` with `itertools.cycle`.

Comment: that will leave some values as ```None```

Comment: Exactly Stef. You are right. Post your comment as an answer.

Comment: OK, this one should answer your question: [How to zip two differently size lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686533/how-to-zip-two-differently-sized-lists) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892180/3080723) if you need iterables instead of lists and you don't know which one is shorter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below code will help you to print a new list as expected

```
from itertools import cycle 

firstlist = ['A','B','C','D','E']
secondlist = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10']

res = [[x, y] for x, y in zip(cycle(firstlist), secondlist)] 
print(res)
```

Comment: thankyou, i would accept this answer, but i can only in 8 minutes

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to combine `zip` with `itertools.cycle`:

```py
import itertools
def zip_cycle_first(a, b):
  return zip(itertools.cycle(a), b)
```

If you don't know which one of `a` or `b` is longer, you can add a test for the length if they are lists:

```py
import itertools
def zip_cycle_shortest_list(a, b):
  if len(a) > len(b):
    return zip(a, itertools.cycle(b))
  else:
    return zip(itertools.cycle(a), b)
```

If you don't know which one is longer and they are both iterables, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53892180/3080723) gives a more versatile solution using `itertools.tee` in combination with `itertools.zip_longest`.