# two unequal lists into a dictionary. give none if key has no value. ignore value does not have a key - python

Tags: python-3.x

There are two lists of different lengths. The first contains keys, and the second contains values. Write a function that creates a dictionary from these keys and values. If the key did not have enough values, the dictionary should have the value None. Values that did not have enough keys should be ignored.

```
a = ['a','b','c']
b = [1,2,3,4,5]

while len(b) < len(a):
  b.append(None)

c = dict(zip(a,b))
print(c)
```

instead of defining 2 lists in the program, how to solve if user wants input 2 lists of unequal length

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686533/how-to-zip-two-differently-sized-lists

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the relative list lengths you will want to use either `zip` or `zip_longest`.

Example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

keys = ['a','b','c']
values = [1,2, 3, 4, 5]

zip_best = zip if len(values) > len(keys) else zip_longest

c = dict(zip_best(keys, values))

print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Edit #1: In response to OP's comment, there are many ways to build lists from user input, but here is one simple way you could construct `keys` and `values` lists from user input if you weren't concerned about error handling:

Example:

```
keys = input("Enter space separated single letter keys: ").split()
values = list(map(int, input("Enter space separated integer values: ").split()))
```

Edit #2: In response to OP's most recent comment below, `zip_longest` provides `None` padding, so in case it wasn't clear, my proposed solution also handles the case where there are more keys than values.

Example:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

keys = ['a','b','c']
values = [1,2]

zip_best = zip if len(values) > len(keys) else zip_longest

c = dict(zip_best(keys, values))

print(c)
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': None}
```

Comment: keys list and values list have been defined in the code. how do i solve it if user wants to input a key list and value list, and then zip them into a dict

Comment: Instead of hard-coding the `keys` and `values` lists as in the example, you could construct those lists from user input using the Python `input` function which prompts the user to enter data then returns that data in string form to the program.  Everything else would be the same.

Comment: thanks. the question also says that if key did not have enough values, the dictionary should  have the value  none

Comment: I believe my solution does that.

Answer (score 0):

A direct way to implement this is by specifying that we need to fill values in dict till all keys are covered.

```
keys = ['a','b','c']
values = [1,2, 3, 4, 5]

res = {keys[i]: values[i] for i in range(len(keys))}
```

Output:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}
```

Comment: This will not get you `None` values for the extra keys when you have more keys than values, right?

Comment: @rhurwitz Yeah thats right. It's just implementing one if else condition but the core code should work :)