# How do I make a string split by every letter

Tags: python, string, termcolor

I want to make a program that makes text rainbow using termcolor but I don't know how to make string's into letters

Code:

```
from termcolor import colored

def rainbow(a):
    alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'
              ,'A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']

    a.split(str(alphabet))

    print(colored(a, 'red'), colored(a, 'yellow'), colored(a, 'green'), colored(a, 'blue'), colored(a, 'magenta'),
          colored(a, 'red'), colored(a, 'yellow'), colored(a, 'green'), colored(a, 'blue'))

rainbow("text")
```

Comment: Your question asks about splits, you have several answers, but then, on comments for those answers, you say you are asking for color stuff instead.  Please clarify what you are asking about.  Colors?  Splitting?  What's not working - paste in the error messsage or output - in this case that might require a screenshot, rather than just text - and what would you like to see instead?  Welcome aboard.

Comment: Also, your `a.split` is not assigned to anything so essentially does not do anything.  `colored(a...`) therefore works on your entire `a` variable, i.e. "text".  start with fixing that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, string is just like a letter list. You can just do like this:

```py
string="text"
for letter in string:
    print(letter)
```

If you want to color the letters in one string, try this:

```py
# Make sure the library is OK, I don't know it, just copy your code.
from termcolor import colored

# fill the dict for all letters yourself
lettercolors = {'a':'red','b':'blue','t':'yellow','e':'blue','x':'green'}
string="text"
for letter in string:
    print(colored(letter,lettercolors(letter)),end='')
print('');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want to change the color of every letter, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean to color the 26 letters by fix or random?

Answer (score 0):

```
def split(word): 
  return [char for char in word]  
    
print(split('text'))
#['t', 'e', 'x', 't']
```

I think you need something like this a simple function.
Your question is not really clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `list()` wrapper:

```
print(list("text"))
```

Output:

```
['t', 'e', 'x', 't']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
import sys

def colored(ch, color):
    # fake function as I dont have termcolor
    sys.stdout.write(f"{ch}.{color} ")

def rainbow(a):

    colors = ['red', 'yellow','green','blue','magenta']

    #double it 1 2 3 => 1 2 3 2 1
    colors2 = colors + list(reversed(colors))[1:]

    #zip brings items of 2 lists together. cycle will just cycle through your
    #colors until a is done.  `a` itself is split merely by iterating over it 
    #with a for loop
    for ch, color in zip(a, itertools.cycle(colors2)):
        # print(f"{ch=} {color=}")
        colored(ch, color)

rainbow("text is long enough to cycle")
```

#### partial output:

```
t.red e.yellow x.green t.blue  .magenta i.blue s.green  .yellow l.red o.red n.yellow g.green  .blue e.magenta n.blue o.green u.yellow g.red h.red  .yellow t.green o.blue  .magenta c.blue y.green c.yellow l.red e.red
```

#### P.S.

Looks like `colors2 = colors + list(reversed(colors))[1:-1]` might avoid doubling up the *red red* outputs when the cycle restarts on colors.  That might require some careful testing.

And I stole [cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4816039).