# How to zip keys within a list of dicts

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-zip

I have this object:

```
dvalues = [{'column': 'Environment', 'parse_type': 'iter', 'values': ['AirportEnclosed', 'Bus', 'MotorwayServiceStation']}, {'column': 'Frame Type', 'parse_type': 'list', 'values': ['All']}]
```

I want a zipped output like this:

```
('AirportEnclosed', 'All')
('Bus', 'All')
('MotorwayServiceStation', 'All')
```

so far the nearest I have got is with the below:

```
for d in dvalue:
    dv = d['values']
    zip_list = zip(dv, d['values'])
    for z in zip_list:
        print(z)
```

Which gives me this as an output:

```
('AirportEnclosed', 'AirportEnclosed')
('Bus', 'Bus')
('MotorwayServiceStation', 'MotorwayServiceStation')
('All', 'All')
```

What do I need to change to get the desired output?

Comment: What is the reasoning behind that data producing that output?

Comment: could be there more than 2 dicts in `dvalues`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand the underlying reasoning, nor how general of a solutions you want (are the dictionaries always two, or can they be more?). Here is something to get you started:

```
dvalues = [{'column': 'Environment', 'parse_type': 'iter', 'values': ['AirportEnclosed', 'Bus', 'MotorwayServiceStation']}, {'column': 'Frame Type', 'parse_type': 'list', 'values': ['All']}]

import itertools

la = dvalues[0]['values']
lb = dvalues[1]['values']

print([(x, y) for x,y in zip(la, itertools.cycle(lb))])
```

This gives the desired output:

```
[('AirportEnclosed', 'All'), ('Bus', 'All'), ('MotorwayServiceStation', 'All')]
```

Inspired from: [Loop over 2 lists, repeating the shortest until end of longest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4815792/loop-over-2-lists-repeating-the-shortest-until-end-of-longest)

Comment: My solution does produce the requested output, If the OP gives more details I will try improving on it